# Which two Others did Ana Lucia kill?

Tags: lost

Somewhere towards Lost Season 2 end, when Ben (Henry) attempts to choke Ana Lucia he tells her that she killed two of good men, referring to Others. The first one was Goodwin, but I don't remember literally anyone else she killed except for Shannon.

**So who is this second person Ben is talking about?**

PS. Please avoid spoilers for Seasons 3-6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She kills an unnamed Other that attacks the camp during the episode "The Other 48 Days". 
From Ana Lucia's Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ana_Lucia_Cortez):

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I should've obviously started from wiki :)

Comment: Not if you want to dodge spoilers! :D definitely don't suggest going on any Lost wiki pages until you've finished the show

Comment: That show was amazing! I was on the edge of my seat with my jaw on the floor at the end of each episode/season. lol :D